# Scroll Restoration on page change doesn't fully scroll to top

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router-v4, scrolltop

Scroll restoration scrolls  8/10ths of the way up the page but not all the way. Not sure if my ScrollToTop component is flawed or if I'm using the route and switch tags incorrectly in the App component. Below are the ScrollToTop and App components respectively.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function ScrollToTop() {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}

export default ScrollToTop;
```

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/explore'>
          <ScrollToTop />
          <Layout className='' currentUser={currentUser} posts={posts} handleLogout={handleLogout}>
            <Explore posts={posts} />
          </Layout >
        </Route>
        <Route path='/meta'>
          <ScrollToTop />
          <Layout currentUser={currentUser} posts={posts} handleLogout={handleLogout}>
            <Meta currentUser={currentUser} posts={posts} />
          </Layout>
        </Route>
        <Route path='/mana'>
          <ScrollToTop>
            <Layout currentUser={currentUser} posts={posts} handleLogout={handleLogout}>
              <Mana currentUser={currentUser} posts={posts} />
            </Layout>
          </ScrollToTop>
        </Route>
        <Route path='/crypto'>
          <ScrollToTop />
          <Layout currentUser={currentUser} posts={posts} handleLogout={handleLogout}>
            <Crypto currentUser={currentUser} posts={posts} />
          </Layout>
        </Route>
        <Route path='/film'>
          <ScrollToTop />
          <Layout currentUser={currentUser} posts={posts} handleLogout={handleLogout}>
            <Film currentUser={currentUser} posts={posts} />
          </Layout>
        </Route> 
      </Switch>
    </div >
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use window object to perform scroll :

```
window.scroll({top:0,behavior:'smooth'})
```

Comment: In the scrolltotop component or app component ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.querySelector('body').scrollIntoView({ 
  block: "start"
})
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast. Where exactly should I insert this code?

Comment: It should be placed in the useEffect()

`useEffect(() => {
    document.querySelector('body').scrollIntoView({ 
      block: "start"
    })
  }, [pathname]);`

replacing `window.scrollTo(0, 0);`

Comment: Oh okay, tried that but it didn't work. Could it have something to do with how I have the <scrolltotop /> tag above the layout tags in the app component?

Comment: I don't think the Router is working correctly. The correct configuration should look like this:


`import { Switch, Route, useLocation, } from "react-router-dom";

function App(){
const location = useLocation();

return(
  <div className="App">
    <Route render={({ location }) => (
       <Switch>
           <Route path="/explore" exact component={Explore} />
       </Switch>
    )} />
  </div>
  )
}

export default App`

Comment: In the Index.js file where the App component is called you need to have this:

`import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom"
import App from './App'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker'

const history = require("history").createLocation

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={history}>
      <App />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)

serviceWorker.unregister()`

You should understand the concept of browser router in React. I suggest reading the docs. :)

Comment: Thank alot going to read into this

Comment: So the fix to my problem was that I had to take overflow-x:hidden off of my app.css file